# Run python program with modules from terminal

Tags: python, cmd

I've been programming Python (3.6.5) with PyDev in eclipse Photon for a few months. It is a small terminal application to extract data from webs (through web scraping) on the corporate intranet that helps me to reduce times in my work, avoiding doing it manually.

The structure is this:

[image]

Start the application from the `main.py` in eclipse showing in the console of this IDE, but I would like to start it from the Windows CMD to later create an `.exe` with `PyInstaller`. If I do `python main.py` it does not find the package classes and returns error.

What parameters does the command need to start the application from the command line in Windows?

Comment: Could you include the import statements from your `main.py` file?

Comment: from bdc_menu import Bdc_menu


def main():
    
    my_bdc = Bdc_menu()
    my_bdc.menu() 


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()

Comment: You should include the 'module' folder, too - i.e. `from classes.bdc_menu import Bdc_menu` ...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `classes.bdc_menu`? Also delete `Daily_Report/__init__.py` because it doesn't need to be a package

Answer (score 0):

I've included `from classes.bdc_menu import Bdc_menu` and deleted `__main__.py`. It works!